# Conda 4.10.3 and Snakemake >5 "__conda_exe" problem

Tags: conda, snakemake

I have the following problem, when I used the command below, it appears that snakemake cannot resolve the creation of the environment using the --use-conda option.

If I not use this option of snakemake and launch the snakefile in an appropriate environment created by conda and not by snakemake, the command execution is ok.

Did someone have the same problem ?

Thanks,

Command:

```sh
snakemake -p -d ./ -s 00_Quality_Check.smk -j 4 --use-conda
```

Versions:

- conda 4.10.3
- python 3.9
- snakemake 5.11

Error message:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
CreateCondaEnvironmentException:
Unable to check conda version:
environment: ligne 10: __conda_exe : commande introuvable

  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 232, in create
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 343, in __new__
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 356, in __init__
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 410, in _check
```

Version:

- conda 4.10.3
- python 3.9
- snakemake 6.7

Error message:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
environment: ligne 10: __conda_exe : commande introuvable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 699, in snakemake
    success = workflow.execute(
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 933, in execute
    dag.create_conda_envs(
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 304, in create_conda_envs
    env.create(dryrun)
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 281, in create
    conda = Conda(self._container_img)
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/deployment/conda.py", line 433, in __init__
    shell.check_output(self._get_cmd("conda info --json"))
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/snakemake/shell.py", line 63, in check_output
    return sp.check_output(cmd, shell=True, executable=executable, **kwargs)
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/home/usr/miniconda3/envs/snake/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'conda info --json' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to this long open conda issue:

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7980

Basically, you can't run conda from within scripts by default.

To address this, previously, people had been putting something like the following in their ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile after the conda stanzas (i.e., after the "# <<< conda initialize <<<"):

```
# Make these functions available to scripts.
export -f conda
export -f __conda_activate
export -f __add_sys_prefix_to_path
export -f __conda_hashr
```

But it looks like something in conda changed recently.  The following may now be sufficient:

```
# Make these functions available to scripts.
export -f conda
export -f __conda_activate
export -f __conda_reactivate
export -f __conda_exe
```

If neither of those work, just use a sledgehammer:

```
# Make these functions available to scripts.
export -f conda
export -f __conda_activate
export -f __conda_reactivate
export -f __add_sys_prefix_to_path
export -f __conda_hashr
export -f __conda_exe
```

Doing the above helped fix the same error reported above for a colleague.

Important: You'll need to log out and log back in for it to work.

To test, put "conda info --json" into a script, and run that script. If you see a wall of JSON, you've fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes it works after adding: export -f __conda_exe in the .bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your conda environment is broken, or you're running snakemake in an environment that doesn't have conda installed.

Look at the last line of the error message:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'conda info --json' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

This is saying that snakemake ran the command `conda info --json` and got an error code back. On many systems, code 127 indicates that the command, `conda` in this case, is not found. The next step in debugging the problem is to run that command manually:

```
$ conda info --json
```

or

```
$ conda info
```

If I'm right, you'll get the `command not found` message. Try reinstalling conda.